How Would I Use SUMPRODUCT with Both Numbers and Length of Characters?
I have a table where in columns A and B have fixed information and C through E (and beyond) is given values and characters.




A
B
C
D
E




1
Index
Factor
Day1
Day2
Day3


2
100
100
3
1
2


3
200
50

3
XX


4
300
250
2
X



5
400
50

2
3


6
500
30
XX
XXX
3


7
600
15


X



What I want to do is to use a SUMPRODUCT formula to multiply the values in the "Day" columns by the "Factor" column.  If the value in a cell is a number, it makes sense, but what I want to do is also include the cells that have "X"'s.
If a cell has "X", it is a 1.  If a cell has an "XX", it is a 2.  And so on.
I have tried the SUMPRODUCT formula over the ranges, which give me the value of the numbered cells in the "Day" columns by the "Factor" column, added together.  As an example, here is the formula for the total of column C:
=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C7,$B$2:$B$7)
Which returns 800.  If I were to consider the "XX" in the column to be 2, that would bring the SUMPRODUCT to 860.




A
B
C
D
E




1
Index
Factor
Day1
Day2
Day3


2
100
100
3
1
2


3
200
50

3
XX


4
300
250
2
X



5
400
50

2
3


6
500
30
XX
XXX
3


7
600
15


X


8
Only SUMPRODUCT
N/A
800
350
440


9
SUMPRODUCT While Considering "X"s
N/A
860
690
555



How would I modify the formula to include the "X"s?

What about
=IF(ISNUMBER(C2:C7),C2:C7,LEN(C2:C7)) * $B2:$B7
If C is not numeric length is taken as value to multiply.

And to retrieve the overall sum:
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISNUMBER(C2:C7),C2:C7,LEN(C2:C7)), $B2:$B7)


That definitely works!  Thank you! I ended up combining your solution with SUMPRODUCT to get =SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISNUMBER(E2:E7),E2:E7,LEN(E2:E7)),$B2:$B7) to get the total to a single number and prevent the spill.
